# EF 6 fluent api IsRequired attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

I have two classes: address and city. I want city property to be required in address class, but when I add `property(p => p.City).IsRequired()` to fluent api I get error that City must non-nullable value type, but when I decorate City property with [Required] annotation everything works. 
So how to do it with fluent api and why `property(p => p.Street).IsRequired()` works for string - string isn'e non-nullable value type

```
public class Address
    {
        public int AddressId { get; private set; }
        public string Street { get; internal set; }
        [Required]
        public City City { get; internal set; }            
    }

public class CIty
{
        public int CityId {get; private set; }
        public string Name {get; internal set;}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to specify the cardinality of a relationship, you need to use the `HasRequired` method instead -- the `Property` method is only used for scalar properties.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired(a => a.City);
```