# how to set nullable type as required with fluent Api in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on an MVC application, I have a Model that contains a property of Type "Gig" (I also defined Gig class), since this property is a reference type (class), it is nullable.

This is my model:

```
public class Notification
{
    [Required]
    public Gig MyGig{ get; set;}
    //More properties defined
}
```

Then I'm trying to replace my model's data annotations with Fluent API, in this way:

public class NotificationConfiguration :EntityTypeConfiguration
    {
        public NotificationConfiguration()
        {
            #region Properties

```
        // how to implement this
        Property(n => n.Gig)
            .IsRequired();

        #endregion
    }
}
```

but when I try to set the previous property as required I got the following error:

> The type 'Gig' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'StructuralTypeConfiguration.Property(Expression>)'

If I change my property type from Gig to string (only for testing purposes), the fluent API code works fine, since string type is also reference type(so it's nullable) as my Gig type, I guess that I need to update my Gig class definition, but I don't know how, any ideas? or how can I implement this...

Comment: if Gig is not an Enum, then MyGig is a navigation property. to define a navigation property as required, you have to write Entity().HasRequired(x=>x.MyGig)...; Note: this also sets the foreign key of this property to a not nullable type.

Comment: I finally got to the same answer you post and it worked

Comment: I realize that, I read your answer. Just wanted to clarify why that is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF 6 fluent api IsRequired attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772327/ef-6-fluent-api-isrequired-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out how to implement the data annotation with fluent Api

```
public NotificationConfiguration()
    {
        #region Properties

        //// how to implement this
        HasRequired(n => n.Gig);

        #endregion
    }
```

That's it